# Using 'or die()' to stop on errors in PHP

Tags: php, boolean-operations

Often in PHP, I see:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
```

Coming from python, I know why this should work, because `or` returns the first value if it is true in a boolean context, and the second value otherwise (see [this](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html)).

But when I try the above technique in PHP in another context, for example something like:

```
$name = "John Doe";
echo $name or "Anonymous";
```

The `or` doesn't return the first value ("John Doe"), it returns 1.

Why does this work in the mysql_query() result case, but not in other cases? Is it bad to use in a mysql_query() case (ignore the fact that I am not returning a useful error to the user)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In PHP, variable assignment (the equals sign) and functions both take precedence over the `or` operator. That means a function gets executed first, then the return value of the function is used in the `or` comparison. In turn when you use two values/variables together with an `or` operator, it compares the two values *first* then returns a Boolean value.

Therefore, the order of evaluation in this example is:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
```

1. **`mysql_query($query)`**
   Returns either a result set for DQL queries such as `SELECT`, or a Boolean value for DDL, DML or DCL queries such as `CREATE`, `DROP`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `ALTER`.
2. **`$result = mysql_query($query)`**
   The result of this query execution is assigned to the variable `$result`.
3. **`$result /* = ... */ or die();`**
   If it's either a result set or `true`, it's considered true (aka "truthy") so the `or` condition is satisfied and the statement ends here. Otherwise the script would `die()` instead.

---

`echo` is a language construct and therefore doesn't actually return a value, so it doesn't run like a function before the `or` comparison is made.

As `$name or "Anonymous"` is always true because the string `"Anonymous"` is non-empty and therefore truthy, the `echo` implicitly converts `true` to `1`, hence that output.

The order of evaluation in this example is:

```
$name = "John Doe";
echo $name or "Anonymous";
```

1. **`$name = "John Doe";`**
   Pretty straightforward — assigns the string **John Doe** to `$name`.
2. **`$name or "Anonymous"`**
   PHP discovers that `$name` contains the string **John Doe**, so what ends up being evaluated is the following:
3. **`"John Doe" or "Anonymous"`**
   Since at least one string is non-empty here, it's considered truthy and the condition is satisfied. This evaluation then returns `true`.
4. **`echo true /* $name or... */;`**
   Converts `true` to `1` and prints the number 1.

Comment: Then I guess this will work with the print-functions like `printf`, or is this the same issue, becaus it produces output? It's a function so it should work, right?

Comment: So `=` is a function but `or` is an operator? I would have thought `=` was also an operator. Also, this is wrong. The `die()` function is not executed before the `or`.

Comment: @faileN: that's correct. `printf()` is a function that returns the number of bytes that were printed, so it'll run similarly to the `mysql_query()` call.

Comment: @rjmunro: `=` is the assignment operator. It's not a function, but in PHP it *also* takes precedence over the `or` operator. I just clarified in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Why should `or` return anything? `or` is a normal boolean operator. `$a or $b` is `true` if either `$a` or `$b` evaluates to `true` and `false` otherwise.

The difference between `||` and `or` is, that `or` has a lower operator precedance, even lower than `=`. This is why

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
```

is same as

```
($result = mysql_query($query)) or (die());
```

whereas

```
$result = mysql_query($query) || die();
```

is same as

```
$result = (mysql_query($query) || die());
```

In your case

```
echo $name or "Anonymous";
```

gets

```
(echo $name) or ("Anonymous");
```

What you are looking for probably is the ternary operator:

```
echo $name ?: 'Anonymous';
```

The above will work as of PHP 5.3, if you have only PHP 5.2 use:

```
echo $name ? $name : 'Anonymous';
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason actually occurred to me shortly after asking the question. It's about operator precedence. The `=` happens before the `or`, so:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
```

is equivalent to:

```
($result = mysql_query($query)) or die();
```

not:

```
$result = (mysql_query($query) or die());
```

as it would be in Python. So this:

```
$a = false or true;
```

will set `$a` to false, not true, which is bound to catch me out at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does something often called "type juggling". In other words: PHP transforms the type of any value for the current use case. Since Strings will be transformed to "true" values, your expression returns true. But echo wants to print an string expression and transforms "true" to 1. Kinda annoying in some cases, but if you know it, you also know how to handle ;)

Check this out, by the way: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 1):

the `or` clause is evaluated first and returns a boolean which the `echo` outputs.  If you want to output text you need a if/else construct like:

```
echo ($name ? $name : 'Anonymous');
```

Comment: or if you're running PHP 5.3+, `echo $name ?: "Anonymous";`

Answer (score 0):

That is because [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is not a function, it's a language construct. It mimicks to be a function, but it really isn't :)

I would never use die() like this, it's kind of rough. You should handle your errors appropriately, don't just bail out.

Comment: I said "ignore the fact that I am not returning a useful error to the user" - that's not part of the question. You've missed the whole problem with this answer. It doesn't matter weather echo is a function or not. `echo (false or true);` or `printf(false or true);` should be the same as `$a = (false or true); echo $a;`

Comment: @rjmunro: The first paragraph (tries to) answer your question. What should `echo $name or "John Doe";` do? `(echo $name) or "John Doe"` OR `echo ($name or "John Doe")` ? That is an important matter. And therefore it is important whether it is a function (with a return value) or a language construct (with no return value).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to replicate that behavior AND output to the screen/browser, you need a function that will return something other than TRUE. printf() can do that for you.

```
echo microtime."&lt;br&gt;";<
$str = "";
printf("%s",$str) or die();
echo "&lt;br&gt;".microtime();
```

If $str is empty, null, or false the die() will be called, otherwise, the script will finish executing.